# How can I join into insert statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Here is my table structure:

```
// pages
+----+-----------------------+--------+
| id |         path          | method |
+----+-----------------------+--------+
| 1  | list_role             | get    |
| 2  | make_role             | post   |
| 3  | edit_role/id          | get    |
| 4  | list_voucher/activate | get    |
| 5  | list_voucher/activate | post   |
| 6  | expire_voucher/id     | get    |
+----+-----------------------+--------+

// role_page
+---------+---------+
| role_id | page_id |
+---------+---------+
```

Now I want to insert multiple rows into `role_page` table according to this array: *(noted that I have `$role_id`)*

```
$arr = [['list_role', 'get'], ['list_voucher/activate', 'get']]
$role_id = 4; // for example
```

So the expected output is:

```
// role_page
+---------+---------+
| role_id | page_id |
+---------+---------+
| 4       | 1       |
| 4       | 4       |
+---------+---------+
```

How can I do that by a join?

---

Currently I do that by a loop on `$arr` like this:

```
$role_id = 4;

foreach($arr as $row) {
    // match the page id
    $page_id = pages::where('path', row[0])->where('method', row[1])->first();

    // insert
    $role_page = new role_page;
    $role_page->role_id = $role_id;
    $role_page->page_id = $page_id;
}
```

Comment: what you are doing is actually a good way to do it

Comment: you should check https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships you can use sync for inserting and updating the pivot table records by giving proper relationship on eloquents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Page Model (you may have to customize this relation)

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_page', 'page_id', 'role_id')
}
```

Then

```
$arr = [['list_role', 'get'], ['list_voucher/activate', 'get']]
$role_id = 4; // for example

$query = Page::query();

foreach ($arr as $page){
    $query = $query->orWhere(function($query){
        $query->where('path', $page[0])->where('method', $page[1]);
    }
}
$pages =$query->get();

foreach($pages as $page){
    $page->roles()->attach($role_id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, upvote. Just one question, when exactly we should use `()` for relations *(which are in models)* ? I mean, you've used `()` for `->roles()->`. But you didn't use `()` for `->relatedPages` *(which is in your previous answer)* . Why?

Comment: when you are using (), it's calling for the relationship query Builder (you can for example, eager load pivot, make a get etc ...) but when you are using without, it's calling the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
$page_id = pages::where('path', row[0])->where('method', row[1])->first();
```

This returns an object.

```
$page_id = pages::where('path', row[0])->where('method', row[1])->first()->id;
```

This will return just the id.

And then in your foreach you can:

```
role_page::create([
           'page_id' => $page_id,
           'role_id' => $role_id
       ]);
```

You do have to explicitly state in your role_page model that it's not plural if your not refering to it in a relationship way:

```
protected $table = 'role_page';
```